# Station-to-Station protocol questions

Tags: diffie-hellman, protocol-design, key-derivation

Basic Station-to-Station protocol which authenticates Bob and Alice if they safely shared their long-term asymmetric public keys.

1. Alice sends Bob her public key $A_K$
2. Bob receives $A_K$ and computes the shared secret key $K$
3. Bob signs with his long-term key $S_B(\mathit{B_K, A_K})$ and encrypts $E(S_B(B_K,A_K), K)$ using AES 128 GCM
4. Bob sends Alice $B_K, E(S_B(B_K,A_K), K)$
5. Alice computes $K$, decrypts $E(S_B(B_K,A_K), K)$ and verifies the sig. using Bob's long-term public key
6. Alice signs $S_A(\mathit{A_K, B_K})$, encrypts $E(S_A(A_K,B_K), K)$ and sends the resulted ciphertext
7. Bob decrypts $E(S_A(A_K,B_K), K)$ and verifies sig. $S_A(\mathit{A_K, B_K})$ using her long-term public key

I have three questions.

1. Before Bob computes $S_B(\mathit{B_K, A_K})$ does he hash $B_K$ and
   $A_K$ using $SHA256$ for example so Alice can hash them herself and compare the hashes?
2. Does Bob use plain $K$ for encryption or does he use a key
   derivation function like $HKDF$?
3. If Bob uses $HKDF$ can he include the salt at the end of the data he
   sends to Alice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. Before Bob computes $S_B(\mathit{B_K, A_K})$ does he hash $B_K$ and
>       $A_K$ using $SHA256$ for example so Alice can hash them herself and compare the hashes?**

Generally the signature generation function already includes a hash operation (which might be SHA-256) so requiring a *separate* hashing step isn't required; it should be *configured* for the signature generation function.

You could use a separate hash if you don't want to involve the private key early in the protocol - but that's the only reason I can think of.

> **2. Does Bob use plain $K$ for encryption or does he use a key
>       derivation function like $HKDF$?**

Depends.

Generally key agreement (which seems to be missing *entirely* from your protocol) will generate a shared secret. But this secret may not be well distributed and / or may be too large. So in that case a separate KDF is required.

Note that *sometimes* a KDF is already configured within the key agreement protocol, so in that case a *separate* KDF is not required - just like with the hash function for the signature generation algorithm. Of course you could still use a separate KDF to derive more keys or keys with a different size if that's needed in your protocol.

> **3. If Bob uses $HKDF$ can he include the salt at the end of the data he
>       sends to Alice?**

Sure, or the salt can be left out altogether. But HKDF does mention that adding a salt is preferred to achieve high amount of security.

Comment: Above should not be seen as a review of your protocol; I do think that there are questionable decisions such as the encryption with key K *besides* the point that key establishment is missing.

Comment: Alice sends the exponential gx to Bob. Bob computes the exponential gy then K = (gx)y. The long-term keys used for signing/verifying are pre-shared.

Comment: Don't see that in your protocol description, but that's OK. Note that you definitively should use a KDF if your key agreement just consists of modular exponentiation (although you can get away with just cropping the shared secret, but that's certainly not best practice).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.